# Lateinit property gives Exception even though it is init

Tags: android, kotlin

My fragment looks like:

```
open lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View { 
    val rootView = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper).inflate(R.layout.xxx, container, false)

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.sss)
    }
}
```

I've seen this error in my log:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tv.lattelecom.app/tv.lattelecom.app.main.MainActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property recyclerView has not been initialized
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2793)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4720)
```

I'm curious, how and why this happens? Also, no clue how to reproduce this error. I guess it happens when application has been some time in background and is/have been rotated. Ideas?

Comment: It's only initialized if `savedInstanceState` is null, which might not be true.

Comment: Also, please, show where and how you use the recyclerView variable after its have to initialized

Comment: @TheWanderer Can u give me an example? I imagine it like that - when onCreateView is being called, that savedInstance will always be null at first - that's when we init views. After that savedInstance should be not null - is that not true? What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you even HAVE that condition? that doesn't make any sense?

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to check if `recyclerView`is initialized yet with `if(savedInstanceState == null)` better use `if(recyclerView::lateinitVar.isInitialized)` for that.

See http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#checking-whether-a-lateinit-var-is-initialized

Comment: well, I've a lot of views that are init there with lateinit property. To problem is somewhere else - in logic of fragments lifecycle. Somewhere inbetween rotation and app being in background (I would risk it to say - by app process being killed).

Comment: In that case please update your question with the necessary information to reproduce the issue. Best would be a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)